# change value after ajax request formik react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I have `Textfields`  with `Formik` validation that can be filled in manually or selected from the select and they will fill in automatically and become disabled, and I have two questions
1. how can I give access to props to the whole class or function where the ajax call occurs
2.how can I change my `values` to an object from an ajax call so that validation passes the test successfully

```
export const Form = props => {
  const {
    values: {
     debtorIin,
   },
    errors,
    touched,
    handleSubmit,
    handleChange,
    handleOnChange,
  } = props;

  return (
    <form className={classes.formWrapper} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <IntegrationReactSelect
        onChange={onChangeDebtor}
        value={debtorValue}
        options={debtorOptions}
        filterOption={filterOption}
        getOptionLabel={getOptionLabelDebtor}
        getOptionValue={getOptionValueDebtor}
      />
      <TextField
       id="debtorIin"
       name="debtorIin"
       disabled={debtorFullInfo && true}
       value={debtorIin}
       helperText={touched.debtorIin ? errors.debtorIin : ""}
       error={touched.debtorIin && Boolean(errors.debtorIin)}
       onChange={change.bind(null, "debtorIin")}
     />
    <form/>
  )

 import {Formik, withFormik } from "formik"
 import { Form,} from "./forms";

 @withFormik(Form)
 export default class InputForm extends Component {
   render() {
   const values = {
     debtorIin: this.state.debtorIin
   }
   const validationSchema = Yup.object({
    debtorIin: Yup.string("")
    .required("required field")
   })

    <Formik
      render={props => {
        return (
          <Form
            {...props}
          />
         )}}
      initialValues={values}
      validationSchema={validationSchema}
      onSubmit={this.submitValues}
  }
 }
```

---

if `console.log` inside the `<Formik render={props ...}/>`, then there is access to these values, and if through `this.props` then there are default values like `history`, `context`, `store` etc...